# Turn non-Kudu to Kudu table in Impala

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

having problem with impala `update statement`, when I used code below

```
update john_estares_db.tempdbhue set QU=concat(account_id,"Q",quarter(mrs_change_date)," ",year(mrs_change_date));
```

it return error message:

```
AnalysisException: Impala does not support modifying a non-Kudu table: john_estares_db.tempdbhue
```

I would like to know if I can either change my non-Kudu table into a Kudu table or is there an alternate for `update statement` for non-Kudu in Impala. TIA

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Kudu](https://kudu.apache.org) is a data store (think of it as alternative to HDFS/S3 but stores only structured data) which allows updates based on primary key. This has good integration with Impala. A kudu table on Imapla is a way to query data stored on Kudu.

In short if you do not already have Kudu installed and setup already you cannot create a kudu table on Impala.

If you have it Kudu installed and setup, then you cannot simply convert a table kudu table. You have to create a new kudu table with similar structure with some primary-key columns (Kudu requires primary key for all tables) and insert data into this from old non-kudu table using sql query `insert into .. select * from ...`.

Comment: thanks for the help, but problem with `insert into .. select * from ....` is it adds rows instead of columns

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of table `john_estares_db.tempdbhue`?
 Hive or other table type, update or upsert is not supported.
You can use `show create table` to check your table type.
[show create table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSnd7.png)
If you have kudu installed you can create a kudu table, and move your data into kudu table,then you can use your update code.